# Varrendo uma entrada pelo scanf não anda na string além do espaço em branco

Tags: c, array, scanf

Estou tentando fazer um programa que leia uma frase e em seguida coloque cada inicial de cada palavra em maiúsculo, se não já estiver. O problema é que eu digito uma frase mas ele só retorna a primeira palavra, nada mais. a palavra está com a primeira letra maiúscula mas as outras palavras da frase não aparecem no *output*.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
char namechange( char abc[], int size);
int main()
{
    int i,n;
    char name[100000];
    scanf("%s", &name);

    namechange( name, n );

}


char namechange( char abc[], int size)
{
    int i, k = 0;
    for ( i = 0; abc[i] != '\0'; i ++)
    {
        int a,b;
        a = abc[i];
        b = abc[i - 1];
        if (i == 0 || 'b' == 8)
           abc[i] = toupper (abc[i]);
    }
    while ( abc[k] != '\0')
    {
        printf("%c", abc[k]);
        k = k + 1;
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este código não faz sentido e nem compila. O principal problema é que o `scanf()` interpreta espaços de forma inadequada, então precisa pedir para ele formatar da forma adequada. Na verdade qualquer coisa além de exercícios simples não se deve usar `scanf()`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

void namechange(char abc[]) {
    for (int i = 0; abc[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (i == 0 || abc[i - 1] == ' ') abc[i] = toupper(abc[i]);
    }
    printf("%s", abc);
}

int main() {
    char name[1000];
    scanf("%[^\n]s", name);
    namechange(name);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/jqzt38). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/nqqswcyc-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Console/ScanfAcceptSpace.c).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, não entendi a mudança ( formatação ) que você fez no scanf. Devo usar o fgets preferencialmente?

Comment: O `fgets()` é o usado em aplicações reais, `scanf()` só para exercícios rápidos ou se fizer muito sentido, o que é raro.

Comment: O `scanf` é frequentemente usado pra fazer as vezes do `strtol()`, para ler e _parsear_ números, mas para strings ele é muito deficiente.

Comment: @Wtrmute o `scanf()` não porque ele só lê `stdin`.

Comment: Verdade. Propriamente seria o `fscanf()` e o `sscanf()`; mas o `scanf()` acaba sendo usado nos casos em que a string viria de `stdin`, como no exemplo, mas também em aplicativos estilo Unix que leem `stdin` e escrevem `stdout`.

Comment: scanf("%[^\n]s", name); tentei usar isso mas ele mostra na tela varios simbolos do código ASCII. Alguém sabe o pq?